# How can I fix this System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: mysql, arrays, database

I am currently trying to fix this issue I am encountering is where the console is giving off errors for the array if anyone knows how to fix this.

The error is on line 246 which is.

```
if (Tamer.DigimonList[3] == null) qry.Add("mercenary3", null);
```

**The Error Log**

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>      at Digital_World.SqlDB.SaveTamer(Client client) in C:\Users\Digimon Master\Dropbox\Digimon Master Project\DMOFrosty'sPost\Server\ServerBuildingSection\DigitalWorld\Database - Game.cs:line 246
>   A connection has closed.

**The Code**

```
        public static void SaveTamer(Client client)
    {
        int lastChar = -1, charId = -1;

        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = Connect())
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `acct` WHERE `accountId` = @acct", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acct", client.AccountID);
                using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
                    if (dr.HasRows && dr.Read())
                    {
                        lastChar = (int)dr["lastChar"];
                        if (lastChar != -1)
                        {
                            charId = (int)dr[string.Format("char{0}", lastChar + 1)];
                        }
                    }
            }

            if (lastChar != -1)
            {
                Character Tamer = client.Tamer;
                using (MySqlConnection con = Connect())
                {
                    Query qry = new Query(Query.QueryMode.UPDATE, "chars", new Tuple<string, object>("characterId", Tamer.CharacterId));
                    qry.Add("charModel", (int)Tamer.Model);
                    qry.Add("charName", Tamer.Name);
                    qry.Add("charLv", Tamer.Level);
                    qry.Add("experience", Tamer.EXP);
                    qry.Add("money", Tamer.Money);

                    qry.Add("partner", Tamer.DigimonList[0].DigiId);
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList[1] == null) qry.Add("mercenary1", null);
                    else qry.Add("mercenary1", Tamer.DigimonList[1].DigiId);
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList[2] == null) qry.Add("mercenary2", null);
                    else qry.Add("mercenary2", Tamer.DigimonList[2].DigiId);
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList.Length >= 3) {
                        if (Tamer.DigimonList[3] == null) qry.Add("mercenary3", null);
                            else qry.Add("mercenary3", Tamer.DigimonList[3].DigiId);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

that may be cause your digimonlist length is actually 3, so array indexes are 0-2

```
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList.Length >= 3) {
```

try replacing `>=` with `>`
so:

```
                        if (Tamer.DigimonList.Length > 3) {
```

Comment: I have tried this fix still but I am still getting the same error.